# How does Wordpress link posts to categories in its database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

At present I am displaying a list of the last 5 posts in a site's blog in its footer using this mysql query:

```
SELECT post_title, guid, post_date FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'Publish' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 5
```

How can I edit this query to restrict the search to a particular category id? I thought it would be as simple as looking for a category field in the posts table but it isn't!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The relations of the Wordpress database is available in the [database diagram](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Database_Diagram).

In your particular case it is:

`wp_posts.ID`
->`wp_term_relationships.object_id`
->`wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id`
->`wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id`
->`wp_term_taxonomy.term_id`
->`wp_terms.term_id`

For querying you need to use an SQL join:

```
SELECT p.ID, t.term_id
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships rel ON rel.object_id = p.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tax ON tax.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tax.term_id
```

But it should be noted that the wordpress database might change at any time, and you should use the Wordpress provided mechanisms (such as [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)) to filter posts from the database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll play it safe, include the functions and use them instead. For future searchers: to use the wp functions externally:
include 'path-to-wp-directory/wp-blog-header.php'