# How to select all the posts from wordpress database based on category name?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

First off, I know this question has been asked many times before and I found quite a few of them on this site and Google.

example: [How does Wordpress link posts to categories in its database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848505/how-does-wordpress-link-posts-to-categories-in-its-database)

However, I can't really understand how to find all the posts based on their category names from wordpress database.

Example: I have a category name called `'restaurants'`.

And I have a few posts under that category.

What is the correct query for this?

also, in the link above, I noticed that the provided answer mentions that the wordpress database might change, so what is the best query to use to make sure these changes doesn't break my code?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Here is one example that i tried which doesn't work.

```
<?php 

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php');
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);

$custom_query = new WP_Query('cat=9'); //your category id 
while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

    //loop items go here

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
```

**EDIT 2:**

I tried this code which doesn't do anything. Just a blank page:

```
<?php

require_once('../wp-config.php');
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);



$args=array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'category_name' => 'restaurants');

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    echo '<div class="Entradas">'.get_the_title().'</div>';
endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();



?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress: Show all posts from specific category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313267/wordpress-show-all-posts-from-specific-category)

Comment: I did a quick search for this and found _many many_ examples. You should try them first. If it doesn't work, show us what you've tried. Also, when it comes to "the database might change", you don't need to worry about that if you're using Wordpress own functions to query it. It's basically only relevant if you're doing your own queries directly to the database.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, yes i found many many answers too and I did mention this right at the start of my question but nothing seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine:

```
  $myposts = get_posts(array(
  'showposts' => -1, //add -1 if you want to show all posts
  'post_type' => 'offer',
  'tax_query' => array(
              array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'offer_cat',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'restaurants' //pass your term name here
                      )
                    ))
                   );

    foreach ($myposts as $mypost) {
    // echo $mypost->post_title . '<br/>';
    // echo $mypost->post_content . '<br/>';
    // echo  $mypost->ID . '<br/><br/>';
    echo '<li class="faq"> <p class="title"><a href="' . get_permalink($mypost) . '">' . $mypost->post_title . '</a></p></li>';}
```

I hope it helps others.